# Maximum product of probabilities

Tags: probability

We know that $P(B_1 ∩ B_2) = 0, P(B_1) = 1/4, P(B_2) = 3/4, P(A) = 1/8$. What is the maximum possible value of the product $P(A | B_1) · P(A | B_2)$?

So far, I calculated that a possible product of both probabilities is 1/64, but I don't know how to ensure that it is the maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

Note that from $P(B_1 ∩ B_2) = 0, P(B_1) + P(B_2)= 1$ follows

- $P(A) = \underbrace{P(A \cap B_1)}_{= x} + \underbrace{P(A \cap B_2)}_{=\frac{1}{8}-x} = \frac{1}{8}$

So, you have to maximize for $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{8}$ the expression
$$P(A | B_1) · P(A | B_2) = \frac{x}{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{8}-x}{\frac{3}{4}} = \underbrace{\frac{16}{3}x\left(\frac{1}{8}-x \right)}_{(\star)}$$

$(\star)$ is a downwards opened parabola which attains its maximum at its vertex in the middle between its zeros $x= 0$ and $x=\frac{1}{8} \Rightarrow x_{max} = \frac{1}{16}$.

Plugging in gives
$$\max_{0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{8}}\left( \frac{16}{3}x\left(\frac{1}{8}-x \right) \right)= \frac{16}{3}x_{max}\left(\frac{1}{8}-x_{max} \right) = \frac{1}{48}$$

Answer (score 0):

First note that $B_1, B_2$ forms a partition over the sampled space, i.e. we have $P(B_1 \cap B_2) = 0$ and $P(B_1) + P(B_2) = 1$. Then by law of total probability, we have

$$ P(A \cap B_1) + P(A \cap B_2) = P(A) = \frac {1} {8} \tag{1}$$

Consider the product

$$ \begin{align} P(A \mid B_1)P(A \mid B_2) 
&= \frac {P(A \cap B_1)P(A \cap B_2)} {P(B_1)P(B_2)} \tag{by definition}\\
&= \frac {16} {3} P(A \cap B_1)P(A \cap B_2) \tag{given}\\
&\leq \frac {16} {3} \left[\frac {P(A \cap B_1) + P(A \cap B_2)} {2}\right]^2 \tag{AM-GM}\\
&= \frac {1} {48} \tag{from (1)}
\end{align}$$

The equality holds when

$$  P(A \cap B_1) = P(A \cap B_2) = \frac {1} {16}$$

and this is admissible as we have 
$$\min\{P(A), P(B_1)\} \geq \frac {1} {16}, \min\{P(A), P(B_2)\} \geq \frac {1} {16} $$

So we conclude that the maximum of the product indeed is $\displaystyle \frac {1} {48}$